# When using Kotlin Coroutines is it best practice to use GlobalScope.launch() or to inherit GlobalScope?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've seen two different uses of Coroutines at my company and I'm wondering which is best?

Usage 1

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    loadMyData()
}
```

Usage 2

```
class MyClass(): GlobalScope {
. . .
    launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        loadMyData()
    }
. . . 
}
```

Is one better than the other?  what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: `GlobalScope` is not recommended to use. Please, see thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not use GlobalScope.launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch)

Answer (score 0):

There's a third option as well

```
class MyClass(): CoroutineScope by GlobalScope
```

But there's a simple question which you should ask when considering how to implement it: Do you want `MyClass` to be a `CoroutineScope` which could be used by other parts of code base as well?

Most of the time the answer should be no and therefore it might be better to use `GlobalScope` directly.

Also I'm assuming, `GlobalScope` is the scope to use here and not go into details of why to consider not using it.