# What is the proper way to launch a coroutine on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a coroutine.  I want it to call two suspend functions in sequence.

The first docs I read said to do this:

```
class Something {
  fun initialize() {
    launch {
      suspendFun1()
      suspendFun2()
    }
}
```

But the `launch` method was not found by Android Studio.  Then I learned that the [official coroutine docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) suggest using `GlobalScope.launch`:

```
class Something {
  fun initialize() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
      suspendFun1()
      suspendFun2()
    }
}
```

But then I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch) that you should not use `GlobalScope.launch`.

So I found another [blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-ii-getting-started-3bff117176dd) explaining that I need a CoroutineScope to call `launch`.  But it doesn't explain how to build one.

Then I found this [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/coroutines-for-android-6f9b9f966056) explaining how to build one for Activities and ViewModels, by implementing CoroutineScope on the class:

```
class Something : CoroutineScope {
  private lateinit var job: Job
  override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

  fun initialize() {
    job = Job()
    launch {
      suspendFun1()
      suspendFun2()
    }
}
```

Then I read this [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/why-your-class-probably-shouldnt-implement-coroutinescope-eb34f722e510) saying I should not implement `CoroutineScope`

```
class Something {
  protected val scope = CoroutineScope(
    Job() + Dispatchers.Main
  )

  fun initialize() {
    scope.launch {
      suspendFun1()
      suspendFun2()
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure I understand the meaning of `Job() + Dispatchers.Main`, as this seems to work as well:

```
class Something {
  protected val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

  fun initialize() {
    scope.launch {
      suspendFun1()
      suspendFun2()
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me simply the best way to do this?  Is it as above?  I'm sure this has been asked already, so I apologize if this is a duplicate question.  But as you can see, there are not clear answers on this.  I would like to hear your input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Last two solutions are fine. [`CoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope.html) creates an empty `Job` if you pass a context without one.

Specifying `job + dispatcher` is just more explicit way to build it as in some cases you might want to use a [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) instead to prevent entire scope from being canceled when one of child jobs fail.

As for building scopes in `Activities` and `ViewModels` instead of declaring your own you can use ones built-in into KTX library by importing KTX fragment module:

```
// add to your apps dependencies
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc02'
```

Now inside your `Activity`s and `Fragment`s you can use [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner).lifecycleScope:androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleCoroutineScope) and inside `ViewModel` a [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#viewmodelscope) which are scopes backed by `SupervisorJob + Dispatchers.Main.immediate` and are automatically canceled when their respective lifecycle is destroyed.

Answer (score 18):

For someone just looking for a simple way to launch a Coroutine with an Android Activity without all the bells and whistles, here's a quick and simple way (but you should still look into learning how to use Coroutines correctly, i.e. with ViewModels & CoroutineScope)

1. Add [androidx.lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) to your app-level build.gradle:

`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"` (check Link above for current version)

2. In the Activity, use the Activity-provided *LifecycleScope* to launch the Coroutine (mostly pseudo-code):

```
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope

class YourActivity {

  override fun onCreate() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      // do your Coroutine Stuff here, i.e. call a suspend fun:
      coroutineFunction()
    }
  }

  suspend fun coroutineFunction() {
    // Use a different CoroutineScope, etc
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      // do some long running operation or something
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using lyfecycleScope when you create own scope?

Comment: The use of `lifecycleScope` in the `onCreate` method ensures that the coroutine is tied to the lifecycle of the activity. This helps in managing the lifecycle-aware behavior, automatically canceling the coroutine when the activity is destroyed.

The use of a custom CoroutineScope (`CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`) inside `coroutineFunction` provides flexibility in terms of choosing a specific dispatcher for the operations within that function. It allows you to control the execution context of the coroutine.

Comment: So you need to pickup something one. Either use lifecycle aware scope or create your own one that is not aware about lifecycle. Alternatively you can use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {} method to define dispatcher for block of code inside of current scope.

Answer (score 14):

I have Coroutines.kt

```
object Coroutines {

    fun main(work: suspend (() -> Unit)) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            work()
        }
    }

}
```

and I use it in my viewmodels by calling Couroutines.main

Comment: whoa, I had no idea you could do a suspending lambda

Comment: @PhillyTheThrilly I found out from a youtube tutorial myself

Comment: Please do NOT do that, it may leak coroutines. Custom `CoroutineScope`s should be properly cancelled according to some lifecycle, otherwise they are as bad as `GlobalScope`. That's why it's advised to use the built-in `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` instead.

Comment: Extremely wrong approach that will cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very similar dilemma, and the OP brilliantly captured a newbie's confusion going about the various resources. In my case, I have no choice other than to create my own `CoroutineScope` because I needed a long-running scope that lives as long as the app process does (it handles interacting with Retrofit using suspend functions), and it lives inside an Android library, having no access to `ViewModel` and other `LifecycleOwner` items.

```kotlin
/**
 * A [CoroutineScope] for HTTP cloud implementations to launch coroutines in. A coroutine
 * dispatcher is not specified because Retrofit will switch to its own custom dispatcher
 * when performing suspending network calls.
 */
internal val networkingScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
```