# What is best practice to use coroutine with fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**Description** 
 I have TabLayout with multiple fragments. I want to save fragment data into Room DB on fragment change/swipe and display data to the user when it back to fragment.

**Currently Using** 
 Currently, I am using coroutine with `GlobalScope.launch` to save into a fragment and it is working fine.

**Questions** 
 
1. What is the best practice to use a coroutine with fragments to save data to DB on fragment change? 
 
2. It is good practice to use `GlobalScope.launch` on fragment change? 
3. if `GlobalScope.launch` is not good to use then what we can use instead of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to use coroutine anywhere is to use the Structured Concurrency to manage all the lifecycle. GlobalScope does not implement the Structured Concurrency.

> 1. What is the best practice to use a coroutine with fragments to save data to DB on fragment change?

You can use [LifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) provided by android.

Inside the fragment you can launch the coroutine with the `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{}` and if you need some operation that should not be cancelled then launch them using `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(NonCancellable){}`

> 2. It is good practice to use GlobalScope.launch on fragment change?

No, GlobalScope is highly discouraged to be used: see more at [Why not use GlobalScope.launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch)

> 3. if GlobalScope.launch is not good to use then what we can use instead of it?

You can use the lifeCycleScope as mentioned by @ianhanniballake.

Comment: You don't need to create your own scope, there's already a [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) you can use.

Comment: those are part of `lifecycle-runtime-ktx`, nothing related to fragments

Comment: Thanks, ianhanniballake and @AnimeshSahu

Comment: @ianhanniballake Is it good to use lifecycleScope.launch{} in Activity or Fragment for making api calls which automatically manages lifecycles?

Comment: @SumitShukla yes, as long as your API uses coroutines, it should change context when required, and at the end you'll be able to change the UI elements because lifecycleScope uses `Dispatchers.Main` :)

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to an activity` In such case we must use viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle scope will make sure the job is destroyed `onDestroyView` and does not survive the entire lifetime of the fragment. @ianhanniballake