# Proper use of coroutines Dispatcher Main and Default

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm trying to do a cup heavy calculation and then want to update the UI.

Below is my code:

```
private fun updateData() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){ //work on default thread
            while (true){
                response.forEach {
                val out = doIntensiveWork()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ //update on main thread
                        _data.postValue(out)
                        delay(1500L)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

is this way of using coroutines okay? As running the entire work on Main also has no visible effect and work fine.

```
private fun updateData() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){ //work on Main thread
            while (true){
                response.forEach {
                val out = doIntensiveWork()
                    _data.postValue(out)
                    delay(1500L)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Which one is recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using `GlobalScope` for the reason described [here](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch).

And you should consider doing heavy computation off the [main thread](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html)

```kotlin
suspen fun doHeavyStuff(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // or Dispatchers.Default
 // ...
}

suspend fun waitForHeavyStuf() = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
  val result = doHeavyStuff() // runs on IO thread, but results comes back on Main thread
  updateYourUI()
}
```

**Documentation**

- [More about Dispatchers here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html)
- I recommend [Roman Elizarov blogs](https://elizarov.medium.com/) about Kotlin Coroutines